# Failed to start Oracle service

Tags: ubuntu, oracle11g, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint Olivia Distribution and wanted to install Oracle 11gXE, but am facing some problems. I followed almost these steps to finish the installation successfully: 
[Installing Oracle 11gXE on Mint and Ubuntu](http://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/installing-oracle-11gxe-on-mint-and-ubuntu/#comment-55256)

But upon running the service `sudo service oracle-xe start` I get this output:

```
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
Failed to start Oracle Net Listener using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr and Oracle Express Database using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus.
```

Any help please?

Comment: Hi, do you really need to install the Oracle 11g this way? or can you consider using a virtual machine that comes with a fully functional Oracle 11g? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html I now we developers like to do all by our selves, but the point is learning to use the database or learning to install it? chances are you are never going to do this on production, (unless of course you're a sysadmin or dbadmin) **changed the link**

Comment: Well you should start looking at the Oracle log files and see what's happening. Or try to start the database manually. If you don't know how to do either, I suggest you head over to the Oracle documentation to learn about the basics.

Comment: @Mat I called the /etc/init.d/oracle-xe in the terminal and I've got the same error. For the sqlplus command, I get this error : 

sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Same for the tnslsnr.

Comment: @anakata If I use a virtual machine, I'll have to do everything within, J2EE programming and stuff, which I don't think would be so helpful

Comment: @Yori - you can access an Oracle instance running inside a VM from the host, so you could still develop form outside. As to your error, have you set the environment up properly, e.g. running `oraenv` (or whatever your instructions say)? The SQL*Plus error sounds like maybe `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't set. But I'm just guessing...

Comment: Ok, I'm downloading the 4Go oracle VM in the link. But, meanwhile, I'll be trying to fix my problem. I tried to search for kind of missing libraries. I used Synaptic Package Manager to get libaio1 shared library. I'm not sure this is the only change I did, but when I did a system reboot, the oracle service seemed to run with no problems. I even can run sqlplus command line. But still can't open the localhost:8080/apex/ page..

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem. Did you install libaio1?. If not, then

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. If I Issue the command sqlplus, the error is -  Error 46 initializing SQL*Plus
HTTP proxy setting has incorrect value
SP2-1502: The HTTP proxy server specified by http_proxy is not accessible

Comment: Helped me too. But I had to reboot my machine in order to get it working. Thanks!

Comment: helped with my install. Thx!